# Show layers TOC in QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: qgis-2, table-of-contents

I somehow closed the layer TOC in QGIS 2.0.1.
How do I get it back? Feeling a bit lost here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Right-click** on the *Tools icons area* (see the red dot on the screenshot below) will display a contextual-menu, then choose "Layers". It will restore the TOC on the left panel.

If you can't see it directly, you will see a new "Layers" tab at the bottom.

[image: QGIS snapshot]